# How do I get possible selection creteria for getContentResolver().query for MediaStore.Images.Media

Tags: android

I want to just images just after a certain date. The code is:

```
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date lastRunDate = sdf.parse(sdf.format(lastRunTIme.getTime()));
        selection = "MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED >=" + lastRunDate;

    final Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            projection,
            selection,
            null,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN);
```

And this is not working. I am sure I am adding correct way to the selection creteria. Can you please help.